# Using NAT gateway and windows activation

Tags: windows, nat, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setup NAT gateway on GCE. I've started Debian and used instruction as they are [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway) to configure it as NAT and I've executed commands below...

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o  -j MASQUERADE

I've started windows server instance with needed tags and if I check public IP on windows instance, it is the public IP of Debian server. Even if I try to open any website on windows server, works as it should.

But things get tricky, when windows tries to active during boot or even if I try to active them manually after boot. I also have issue with windows update installation when using NAT gateway. If I start windows server without NAT, everything works ok...

This is the error from server console for activation with nat...

02/11/2017 15:25:26  Activating Windows(R), ServerDatacenter edition (21t12779-b119-4t67-ad76-eece0e1ad74b) ...
02/11/2017 15:25:26  Error: 0xC004F074 The Software Licensing Service reported that the computer could not be activated. No Key Management Service (KMS) could be contacted. Please see the Application Event Log for additional information.

Any hints what could be the issue...?

Best regards,
Matjaz

Comment: Is this license provided by you or by Google?

Comment: It is provided by google...

Comment: Then you'll need to contact google about it.

Comment: On the Windows computer that is attempting to activate, is it able to find the KMS DNS SRV record, or have you configured it to use a specific KMS using `cscript %systemroot%\system32\slmgr.vbs /skms`?

Comment: I've tried nslookup for kms server (used default google) and it can be resloved even on a Windows computer behind nat but if I try to telnet kms server, telnet does not work if it is behind nat (works if without nat). Can I setup routing so everything except host for kms is send through nat...?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it can't be done...

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/getting-support-for-windows-instances

Windows images cannot activate without a network connection to kms.windows.googlecloud.com, and stop functioning if they do not authenticate within 30 days. Create an external IP for your Windows instances so they can authenticate.

Just out of curiosity I've setup external IP for server behind nat and setup routing for kms server IP to go through default internet gateway but no success...